# Pizza Positioning Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, logic-grid

### Seating Arrangements

[image]

Me ( I'm Johnny) and my brothers Vinny, Mickey, Smitty, Gino, and Pauly always take the same seat when we have our weekly pizza party at our favorite Pizza place - and we always sit at a round table.

The following diagram indicates our seating.

### Seat Positions

[image: Pizza]

**The following is known:**

1. Smitty's seat is separated from Johnny's seat by exactly one of our other brothers.
2. Mickey's seat number differs from Vinny's and Smitty's, positively or negatively, by 2 and 5 in one order or the  other.
3. Vinny's number is 1 larger than Gino's number.
4. Johnny's number is either 1 larger or 1 smaller than Pauly's number.

## Which brother sits in which seat?

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

> Mickey's seat number differs from either Vinny or Smitty by 5, so that means Mickey must be in seat 1 or 6.
>  Vinny differs from Mickey by 2 or 5, so he must be in seats 1, 3, 4, or 6, but he can't be in seat 1 because his seat number is larger than Gino's.
>  Vinny also can't be in seat 6. If he were in seat 6, Smitty would be in seat 3 (2 apart from Mickey) and Gino would be in seat 5 (one less than Vinny). But this leaves nowhere for Johnny and Pauly to sit one apart from each other.
>  Vinny also can't be in seat 4. If he were, Gino would be in seat 3 and with Mickey in 6 and Smitty in 1, and again there is no way for Johnny and Pauly to sit one apart from each other. 
>  So Vinny must be in seat 3. Then Gino is in seat 2. Mickey is in 1, and Smitty is in 6. This leaves Johnny and Pauly in 4 and 5. Johnny must be in 4 based on clue 1.
>  
>  So:
>  1 Mickey
>  2 Gino
>  3 Vinny
>  4 Johnny
>  5 Pauly
>  6 Smitty